# Is there a limit of in-app purchases in Windows Phone 8 app?

Tags: windows-phone-8, in-app-purchase

We've published WP8 app for purchasing magazines/newspapers using in-app purchases. We've created single in-app purchase for each single issue + some subscriptions and 10pack in-app purchases, together **there is 134 in-app purchases defined in the WP Store for the app**.

The problem is, the **CurrentApp.LoadListingInformationAsync() API returns only the list of first 100 in-app purchases**. Is this expected behavior that **Windows Phone 8 app can use only 100 in-app purchases?** I've not found any single information on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206949%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) about limit of in-app purchases for single WP8 app. Note we already know about the limit of 200 items in Windows 8 store.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I've found a solution for this bug, when **CurrentApp.LoadListingInformationAsync()** returned only first 100 published products:
This is actually undocumented feature/bug in this method, it returns only first 100 products in case you have created more than 100 items for your app.

In order to get information about remaining products, you need to use [this API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj635249.aspx):
**CurrentApp.LoadListingInformationByProductIdsAsync(listOfIds)**. It returns info about any published product, if you know the product.Id. Thanks to this method we're able to fix our app and provide to users option to buy any published product.

I've also sent message to Microsoft support, if they can give me any clarification regarding this unexpected behavior. In the meantime I'm glad the solution with the second method works.

Comment: Did you ever get a reply from Microsoft?

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a link to the strategy for dealing with the in-app purchase limit:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Dn532256(v=win.10).aspx