# Windows "Runtime" app (PC vs Phone) - Is it the same notification API?

Tags: c#, push-notification, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I'm beyond confused trying to grasp what is what regarding Microsoft's so called "Runtime" Apps (also called "Universal" or the convergence of Windows 8.1).

I'm currently building an app for both Windows 8.1 and Phone 8.1 and wondering, is the Notification API exactly the same? Since I'm having trouble understanding what is what, it's hard to google what it is I'm after.

If I googled for "Phone 8 apps" it's obviously wrong, because they are something different.

Optimally I just wanna use the exact same code for the phone app as for the Windows 8.1 app, is that possible?

Sorry if I made no sense and thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create an universal app, you'll be able to share the exact same notification code between desktop and phone, as they both share the same runtime (called WinRT). Any code you find to implement notifications on Windows 8.1 is directly applicable on Windows Phone 8.1

Comment: Ahh thanks for confirming that! Is it the same with In-app purchase? (Sorry this isn't included in the question)

Comment: @user2422321 Honestly, I haven't tried implementing in-app purchases, so I can't be 100% sure. But as far as I know, the API is the same, especially since IAP can be shared between phone and desktop (so the user only has to buy it once). If you need to find documentation, the two keywords to keep in mind are "universal apps" and "winrt"

Comment: @user2422321 in-app purchases are the same, only be careful, WP still returns max 100 products ([bug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19890391/is-there-a-limit-of-in-app-purchases-in-windows-phone-8-app)) and if you use XML file for testing the prices have a lot of decimal places ([bug](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28150692/in-app-product-formattedprice-with-many-decimal-places)).